# Recordset Null Value not being detected in null check

Tags: null, vb6

I'm looping over rows in a recordset and assigning my variables values based on values of field in the current row. I keep getting an error

> Invalid use of Null

When debugging I found this issue was on the following line

```
TurnoverPTD = rsPeriod.Fields(0)
```

To fix this, I changed it to the following

```
If rsPeriod.Fields(0) = Null Then
   TurnoverPTD = 0
Else
   TurnoverPTD = rsPeriod.Fields(0)
End If
```

Yet, I'm still getting the same error. When debugging, holding the cursor over the top line shows `rsPeriod.Fields(0) = Null` in the tooltip, however I'm not sure if this is just indicating that that's what the line of code says?

How else can I check for Null and why isn't my method working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a method similar to the `IsDBNull` that mthod exists in `VB.NET`.

The method, `IsNull`, takes a parameter (`rsPeriod.Fields(0)`) and returns a boolean value.

You can use this method in your `If` statement, as below.

```
If IsNull(rsPeriod.Fields(0)) Then
   TurnoverPTD = 0
Else
   TurnoverPTD = rsPeriod.Fields(0)
End If
```

It's better to use this rather than `If x = Null` as in the code, `IsNull` is checking if the value is null or not. Using the = operator means that it will try to compare the value - But you can't compare a value to Null in this way.

Therefore, when comparing a `RecordSet` field, this is the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use:

```
If IsNull(rsPeriod.Fields(0).Value) Then
```

Don't rely on default properties, and there is no need to test whether `True = True`.

Answer (score -1):

Change it to:

```
If rsPeriod.Fields(0) Is Nothing Then
   TurnoverPTD = 0
Else
   TurnoverPTD = rsPeriod.Fields(0)
End If
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error with this code, although the `rsPeriod.Fields(0) Is Nothing` tooltip is still there, so the value is certainly null.